# How to enable the pop up option in a calendar in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, popup

My calendar uses calendar overlay. I am trying to get the event information to pop up on the same page. Currently the event information opens a new tab, I am not too familiar with the javascript options and am looking for any alternative.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Edit the Calendar view page.

[image]

2.Add the **Script Editor** web part.

[image]

3.Paste the below script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function () {
$("a[href*='DispForm.aspx']").each(function () {
$(this).attr("onclick", "openDialog('" + $(this).text() + "','" + $(this).attr("href") + "')");
$(this).attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
$(this).removeAttr("target");
});
}, 900);
});
 
function openDialog(title, url) {
var options = {
title: "Calendar - " + title,
 
autoSize:true,
url: url
};
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
</script>
```

[image]

======================== **Updated Answer** ======================

Please change the first line of code to

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Does it work?

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. But I tried to put this in and it did not do anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, VirtualGirl7. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!